# Ambiguity error accessing equality comparison operator in G++

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance, comparison-operators

In case of multiple inheritance if all parent classes have their own equality comparison `operator ==`, and the child class has a (friend) function `operator ==`, as in the example:

```
struct A {
    bool operator ==(const A&) const = default;
};

struct B {
    bool operator ==(const B&) const = default;
};

struct C : A, B {};

constexpr bool operator ==(const C&, const C&) { return true; }

static_assert( C{} == C{} );
```

GCC prints the following error about ambiguity in an attempt to compare child objects:

```
 error: request for member 'operator==' is ambiguous
   13 | static_assert( C{} == C{} );
 note: candidates are: 'bool B::operator==(const B&) const'
 note:                 'bool A::operator==(const A&) const'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W3qer376d

This error looks surprising, since `operator ==(const C&, const C&)` shall be preferred as the most suitable to the actual arguments. Is it simply a defect in GCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the global operator `operator==(const C&, const C&)` has priority. However the compiler "want to know" all the possibilities in order to decide: In other words: as soon as you try to use the `operator==` the compiler requires you to have no ambiguities, even if the required alternative is not between the ambiguous one.

---

```
struct C : A, B { using A::operator==; };
```

This resolves the ambiguity and allows you to use the global `operator==`

https://onlinegdb.com/nxMjPN4NC

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    bool operator ==(const A&) const { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; return true; };
};

struct B {
    bool operator ==(const B&) const { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; return true; };
};

struct C : A, B 
{
    //using A::operator==; // Uncomment this to make it work.
};

bool operator ==(const C&, const C&) { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; return true; }

int main()
{
    C c1, c2;
    
    c1==c2;

    return 0;
}
```

Result (when resolved):

> C

Comment: Thanks! If GCC is right, does it mean that Clang is wrong in accepting the code from the question?

Comment: I think ISO don't accept ambiguities. But I can't find the reference right now.

Comment: "In other words: as soon as you try to use the operator== the compiler requires you to have no ambiguities" - I may be wrong, but I don't think this is true. [Ambiguity matters only](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over#footnote-120) if the _best_ viable function is ambiguous. I would argue that GCC is wrong to reject the original program as both the derived member `operator==` overloads are worse overloads than the non-member `operator==`.

Comment: This answer it, thank you. I was referring to the "ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worse conversion for the second" message, but it is a different case.

Comment: @dfrib - GCC is correct. [Name lookup precedes overload resolution](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup#general-1.sentence-5) and it must be unambiguous too. GCC is rightfully complaining that there is an ambiguity when forming the member candidate set.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I see, thanks. The (non-normative) note I quoted above is arguably a bit confusing then (_"Note that this construction can yield candidate call functions that cannot be differentiated one from the other by overload resolution because they have identical declarations or differ only in their return type. The call will be ambiguous if overload resolution cannot select a match to the call that is uniquely better than such undifferentiable functions."_), but I guess then that this cover cases where name lookup has already succeeded?

Comment: @dfrib - Yes. The simplest example would be `struct A { bool operator== (A const &) const; }; bool operator== (A const&, A const&);` - Both member and non member are unambiguously found by their [respective name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.oper#3), but then overload resolution fails.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I fully agree now (thanks!) with name lookup -> needs to succeed -> overload resolution. I think the non-normative note is mostly confusing at this point, as it speaks of "undifferentiable functions" when the normative wording for overload resolution already clearly describes how ranking of viable functions works, and moreover never mention the word "undifferentiable".

Comment: I reported MSVC problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/false-acceptance-of-ambiguous-comparison-operation/1544698